# How to get warnings about variables assigned to, but not used anymore?

Tags: c, gcc, compiler-warnings, clang

The following file `foo.c` is a simplified version of a subtler bug I found in my code.

```
int b;

void bar(int a);

void foo(int a)
{
  bar(a);
  a = 42;
}
```

The line `a = 42` is in fact a typo in my code: I meant `b = 42`.  I don't expect the compiler to detect that I made a typo, but I would like the get a warning that I am assigning to a local variable (or a function parameter) that is not going to be used anymore.  If I compile this file with

```
% gcc-4.6 -Wall -Wextra -pedantic -O3 -c foo.c
```

I get absolutely no warning.  Inspecting the generated code shows that the assignment `a = 42` is not performed, so `gcc` is perfectly well aware that this instruction is useless (hence potentially bogus).  Commenting the call to `bar(a);` does produce a warning `warning: parameter ‘a’ set but not used [-Wunused-but-set-parameter]`, so it seems like `gcc` will not warn as long as `a` is used somewhere in the function, even if it is *before* the assignment.

My questions:

1. Is there a way to tell GCC or Clang to produce a warning for such case?  (I could not get clang 3.0 to produce any warning, even with the call to `bar` removed.)
2. Is there a reason for the actual behavior?  I.e, some cases were it is actually desirable to assign to local variables that will be thrown away by the optimizer?

Comment: Make the function argument a `const` and the compiler will complain: `void foo(int const a) { /* ... whatever ... */ }`

Comment: @pmg: Changing the source is not an option: I want to detect similar useless assignments in my existing code base.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no `gcc` or `clang` option to my knowledge that can warn about this useless assignment.

`PC-Lint` on the other hand is able to warn in this situation.

> **Warning 438 Last value assigned to variable 'Symbol' not used** -- A value had
>   been assigned to a variable that was not subsequently used. The
>   message is issued either at a return statement or at the end of a
>   block when the variable goes out of scope.

Answer (score -1):

The compiler will detect that this is dead code and optimise it out anyway. If you look at the assembly listing (provided you tell gcc to optimise), then you will find the assignment is non-existent.

Comment: As noted in the original question, I've already told `gcc` to optimize, and I have already noted that the assignment it optimized away.  The question is why the compiler will not let me know that I wrote something useless, or how can I configure it to let me know.

Comment: You're not answering the question. He wants the compiler to detect such code, when the programmer didn't notice the mistake (and therefore won't dig into listing files).